# how to insert 200 records via a single Api call using bulk api in salesforce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

How do i add multiple records in a single api call via the bulk api using the databasedotcom gem ? right now i using the normal activerecord type methods to insert which takes one api call per record

Comment: bulkAPI is well documented (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/), are you having some problems with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The databasedotcom gem does not support bulk API as it is just a wrapper for the SFDC REST API
Check here: https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/50

You will have to implement Bulk API on your own, I could not find any ruby gem for it. Here is the reference http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/

Answer (score 1):

you can look at [rforce](https://github.com/undees/rforce) gem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857318/ruby-rails-how-can-i-create-multiple-records-in-salesforce-with-one-api-call) is an example of inserting multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the salesforce_bulk gem that is used for Bulk API calls.  Here is an article on how to use it:  http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Accessing_Salesforce_Data_From_Ruby

Comment: salesforce_bulk gem is not updated and compulsory uses usoername password combo for authentication. Instead i have re written the same gem which uses all authentication method with governor limits.https://github.com/yatishmehta27/salesforce_bulk_api

Answer (score 0):

Get records from SFDC.

1. `rails generate scaffold_controller Account Name:String`
2. Gemfile
   `gem "databasedotcom"`
   `gem "databasedotcom-rails"`
3. create databasedotcom.yml

   `//Create remote access in SFDC

   client_id:

   client_secret:

   username:

   password:

   host: login.salesforce.com
   debugging: true 
   version: 25.0`
4. delete public/index.html
5. routes.rb
   `root :to "accounts#index"`
   `resources :accounts`
6. controllers/accounts_controller.rb
   `include Databasedotcom::Rails::Controller`

   change `"account.destroy"` to `"account.delete"`

   `create @account['OwnerId'] = '00590000000pQOL'` (required field)
7. Remove `.error` in views/_form.html.erb

Comment: It s doesnt use the bulk api .. hence using Databasedotcom gem will finish ur governor limits

Comment: Can this be formatted (e.g. with sample code) and fleshed out a little? That would make it more useful to people who find this question via search, if it's actually effective.